# Autocomplete and how to let it understand lowercase and uppercase

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I have a db in Ruby of a seed file that creates cities in the U.S, ie:

```
City.create(:name => "Sausalito,CA", :state => "CA")
```

However, upon testing the autocomplete, the database only recognizes each pre-loaded location if I format correctly.

So it will see 'Sausolito, CA' as an input but not 'sausolito, ca' as one.

Is this an easy fix on the db or is it a search box issue?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Here is the call:

```
    class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  def autocomplete

    render :json => City.autocomplete_name(params[:term]).collect{ |city| {:value => city.id, :label => "#{city.name}"} }


  end

end
```

AC:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :state
has_many :searches

scope :autocomplete_name, lambda {|name|

    where("cities.name LIKE ?", "#{name}%")
 }

end
```

Comment: jQueryUI - is that what you mean?

Comment: No, now are you loading the values from your database? Are they pre-loaded into the page, or does the autocomplete call a method on your controller whenever you start typing? I'd post more code on how exactly your autocomplete is set up.

Comment: A method is called on the controller upon the user typing the first letter...let me add some code to the original post.

Comment: Your updated post only shows the migration, not the actual controller code...

Comment: Sorry, brain fart - here is the controller

Comment: Ok, can you post the content of your City model's `autocomplete_name` method?

Comment: I wouldn't trigger on the first character. I'd let the user get several letters in before trying to autocomplete, in order to reduce network and DB load.

Comment: It triggers on the second letter - but still haven't figured out how to allow for it in lower and uppercase

Answer (score 1):

What database you are searching against? For MySQL, you may use the Order By clause to achieve case insensitivity - see below....

> Also I found it strange that STRCMP() is case-sensitive, but ORDER BY is case-insensitive.

You may find more information here. Even I have wondered that in some situations, MySQL selects are case insensitive but I didn't really invest time in figuring out why it was not consistent, today I learned it!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Best approach would be to load all those records in memory, and storing lowercase versions of those strings. Your performance will be much better then hitting database for auto-complete capability.

Comment: Ok. Shouldn't he be caching results in memory? Unless there is very limited traffic, I cannot imagine database (that too, sqlite) holding up for all those auto-complete ajax calls!

Comment: SQLite just for local testing :)

Answer (score 1):

If your database is loading queries using a `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE name LIKE '$typed%'` -type query, you could possibly use `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER("$typed%")`

Comment: And don't embed the variable into the query. That's a great way to get hacked by a SQL injection.

Comment: Let's pretend the line above this is `$typed = mysql_real_escape_string($typed);`, mmk?

Comment: It looks like SQLite supports the `lower()` function as well.  `where("lower(cities.name) LIKE lower(?)", "#{name}%")`.  And sanitizing inputs is a language-independent concept.